# Return html from method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to return HTML straight from a model method to show the last reply to a Topic.

My Topic model:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :replies

   def last_reply
       self.replies.last.name
   end 
end
```

and the view:

```
<%= topic.last_reply %>
```

It renders HTML with speech marks around it indicating a string. How do I get rid of these speech marks?

My thought:

```
def last_reply
    self.replies.last.name.html_safe
end
```

I'm scared of doing this incase someone has embedded JavaScript or something as a reply name. I have validations to stop this, but I still want to be doubly-safe. If embedded JavaScript was to be displayed, I would obviously want it literally displayed on the page and not processed by the browser. Does `html_safe` do this?

Should I be doing this in a decorator or helper? I feel ERB tags should never have 'programming' in them as they should simply contain one method call to display information:

*view:*

```
<%= decorate_last_reply %>
```

*decorator:*

```
def decorate_last_reply
    model.last_reply #=> "Yep a string I am"
end
```

I still want to know how I should be returning HTML without those speech-marks. I could probably use the .gsub() method to get rid of them, but I want to know how to do it properly.

Comment: You are not going to get "how to do it properly" because nothing about this is proper. Using Rails is about sticking to convention, use the controller to do this properly.

Comment: @wurde Shouldn't it be all about fat models and skinny controllers? Creating an instance method rather than a controller method will make it easier to develop in future because whenever I need to get the last reply I just need to fire off a `<#>.last_reply`, regardless of where I am in the app, even if I'm creating a mailer. This feels nicer, and even if it isn't in the interest of DRY (a shared controller method would save as many characters as an instance method) it still unclutters the controller.

Comment: @wurde I agree with Starkers; this is very much a perfect situation for view helpers (or some other similar construct). What convention do you feel is violated in this case?

Comment: I agree 'view helpers' is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

Logically `topic.last_reply` should return the last record - an object. You could do that by scoping or method. Then I would pass it to helper or just create a helper `topic_last_reply` with getting topic.last_reply and partial rendering